# Call a function of a class from another function of same class

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, es6-class

```
class Frame {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init(){
    setTimeout(function(){this.secondFunction()}, 2000); // DOES NOT WORK
  }

  secondFunction(){
  }
 }
```

I am trying to call a function of a class from another function of same class. When I call it directly with "this.secondFunction()" then it works fine. But when I move it insode of a setTimeout or a JQuery function, it does not work and throws error "this.secondFunction is not a function". I think this is because the "this" changes to timer object when I call it from setTimeout. What's the correct way to call the function in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` inside the `setTimeout` function isn't what you want. Use an arrow function:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.secondFunction();
}, 2000);
```

The issue was that the function inside `setTimeout` was changing the `this` reference from the new instance to the `setTimeout`, which wasn't what you wanted. An arrow function inherits its `this` binding, so it'll work perfectly.

An ES5 equivalent would be to use `bind` outside of the callback, to change the binding.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.secondFunction();
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

Comment: Yes I know @CalvinGodfrey, I am in the process of adding that to my answer.

Comment: Please check for dupes before answering.

Comment: Thanks, the arrow function solved the issue!